# ChromeDriver Does Not Open Websites

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour when testing Chrome via selenium webdriver.

Instead of navigating to pages like one would expect the 'get' command leads only to the download of tiny files (no type or.apsx files) from the target site.
Importantly - this behavior only occurs when I pass `chrome_options` as an argument
to the Chrome driver.

The same testing scripts work flawless with firefox driver.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options # tried with and without 

proxy = '127.0.0.1:9951'  # connects to a proxy application 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()    
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('whatismyip.com')
```

Leads to the automatic download of a file called download (no file extension, Size 2 Byte).
While calling other sites results in the download of small aspx files.
This all happens while the browser page remains blank and no interaction with
elements happen = the site is not loaded at all.

No error message, except `element not found` is thrown.

This is really strange.

Additional info:
I run Debian Wheezy 32 bit and use Python 2.7.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `http://www.whatismyip.com`?

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. Yes. same result. The problem only comes to bearing when I put in the chrome_options. I am not sure to use the Desired Capabilities instead, as it is deprecated and supposedly not working perfectly with ChromeDriver.

Comment: What does your `import` look like? @JohnSlathon

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post accordingly. I tried with and without explicitly importing the Chrome Options submodule. Changed the lower statements each time accordingly (webdriver.ChromeOptions() or Options())

Comment: Beats me, sorry @JohnSlathon

Comment: Hey, thanks Jonathan Davis! Update: It is only the proxy statement which appears to cause trouble. Just initializing the driver with an empty ChromeOptions object does not cause any trouble.

Comment: Have you tried `--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9951` ?

Comment: Leads to same behavior. ChromeDriver might either use the proxy or not. But webaccess is definitely not blocked.

Comment: How do you start the Firefox instance?

Comment: Thanks, Louis - isn't it in the code sample I provided?

Comment: And you're sure the problem isn't in your proxy server? I wouldn't be surprised if the proxy is mishandling a header... (content-type perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and captured the traffic on localhost using an SOCKS v5 proxy through SSH. It is definitely sending data through the proxy but no data is coming back. I have confirmed the proxy was working using Firefox.

I'm running Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. My Chrome browser gives me the following message when I try to configure a proxy in its settings menu:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the
>   system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not
>   supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man
>   google-chrome-stable for more information on flags and environment
>   variables.

Unfortunately I don't have a man page for google-chrome-stable.

I also discovered that according to the selenium documentation Chrome is using the system wide proxy settings and according to their documentation it is unknown how to set the proxy in Chrome programmatically: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy